# In Android use setVideoFrameRate() after prepare(), start() while capturing video

Tags: android

How to change frame rate using `setVideoFrameRate()` in Android after `prepare()`, `Start()` using the api?

I have set the framerate to 30fps (default) before capturing video on Android, after `prepare()`, `start()` api I want  to invoke `setVideoFrameRate()` again to change frame rate to 120fps. Is it possible to do that?

```
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MP‌​EG_4);
. .
setCaptureRate (double 30);
prepareVideoRecorder();
mMediaRecorder.start();
. . .
setCaptureRate (double 120);
. . .
mMediaRecorder.stop();
```

This is sort of `psuedoCode` which I want to implement and Can I use  `setVideoFrameRate()` instead of `setCaptureRate()`?